# SqlServerDsc 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' account permissions

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dsc

On my test environment (Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2017), I have a working Powershell DSC configuration in push mode using SqlServerDsc, in which I add logins to the server, add database users to database roles etc. I don't use `PsDscRunAsCredential` so the Local Configuration Manager on the server uses SYSTEM to connect to the SQL Server instance. In SQL Server, I can see the connection coming in as domainname\computername$. No surprises there.

What I don't understand is how this can work, as domainname\computername$ is not configured as a login, nor are 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' and 'BUILTIN\Administrators'. `EXEC xp_logininfo 'domainname\computername$', 'all';`, `EXEC xp_logininfo 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'all';` and `EXEC xp_logininfo 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'all';` return empty. I've also run a bunch of security report scripts I've found online, but none of them include useful information.

The SQL Server service runs under a low-privileged domain account.

Does 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' have some kind of implicit sysadmin permissions in SQL Server? I've been working with SQL Server for quite a few years now, but I can't figure this one out. The only way I can make DSC *stop* working ('Failed to connect to SQL instance') is by creating a login for 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' and disabling it, which somehow overrides the implicit permissions (if that's what it is).

Any ideas or pointers? Thanks!

**Update:** The behavior is the same on a freshly installed instance.

Comment: That was probably the built in account chosen during install. Unless you disable it, that account has elevated privileges. This account can be selected as the account for the sql agent workers to do work as.

Comment: Unable to reproduce *directly* -- on my machine `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` has an explicit login, but when I remove it `psexec -s "sqlcmd" -Q "select suser_sname()"` yields "Login failed for user <domain>\<machinename>$". This suggests that possibly, there's another way on your machine where the local machine account has permissions. Does `select [name] from sys.server_principals where type = 'U'` give any clues?

Comment: @RossBush That could perhaps be it.  Can't really remember how this was set up.  I'm going to install a fresh server, and see if I can reproduce it there.